# Join two ascending link lists

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to join two linked lists which are already in ascending order into one link list, this is what i have so far, 
all though my problem is if i have say two lists: [1,2,3,4,5,6] and [4,5,6,7,8] the [6,7,8] part of list 2 will not add to joined list because the first for loop(;list1!=null||list2!=null) continues to execute until list2 = null, but i have used || operand to try and stop this but it continues to do so?

```
private static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Cell<T> JoinLists(Cell<T> list1, Cell<T> list2)
{
    Cell<T> temp = null;
    for(;list1!=null||list2!=null; list2=list2.next){
        System.out.println("for 1: "+linkedListToString(list2));
        for(;list1!=null; list1=list1.next){
            System.out.println("for 2: "+linkedListToString(list2));
            if(list1.first.compareTo(list2.first)>0){
                temp = new Cell<T>(list2.first,temp);
                break;
            } else {
                temp = new Cell<T>(list1.first,temp);
            }
        }
    }
 for(;list1!=null;list1=list1.next){
    temp = new Cell<T>(list1.first,temp);
  } 
 for(;list2!=null;list2=list2.next){
    temp = new Cell<T>(list2.first,temp);
  } 
for(;temp!=null;temp=temp.next){
    list1 = new Cell<T>(temp.first,list1);
}
return list1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this behavior because upon completion of first iteration of inner `for` loop, `list1` gets exhausted i.e. becomes `null`. So, from second iteration on wards of outer `for` loop, since `list2` is `not null`, it keeps on increment until it becomes `null`.

With your existing logic, you need to break out from outer loop when `list1` exhausts (taking care of overlapping values).